# Spring Boot 3 Migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We are planning to migrate from Spring boot 2 to Spring boot 3

in existing config we have some spring data JPA methods like

```
@Query("UPDATE PropertyJpaEntity c SET c.propertyValue = REPLACE(c.propertyValue, ?1, '') WHERE c.propertyName = 'archiveId' AND c.toolId = ?2")
```

but getting error
Parameter 1 of function 'replace()' has type 'STRING', but argument is of type 'java.lang.String'
after migrating to spring boot 3 (hibernate 6)

this works fine if i change this to native sql

Spring boot version i am upgrading to is 3.2.3

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-orm-5-3-removed-support-for-positional-parameters/573) and [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/migration-guide.adoc#changes-to-positional-query-parameter-handling)